# How to remove grid effect from image?

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, style-transfer

I am training a model to transfer the style from an image to another, and I am cropping images to do that crop-by-crop. Then, when I reconstruct the resulting image, I get something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kpG1.jpg).

Do you know how I can remove this grid effect from my image?

Comment: By breaking the image into separate regions you are introducing discontinuities that are visible when you put them back together again.  Ideally you would not crop the image.  I'm not sure how you would do this, but you need to smooth the transition between the boundaries.  You could use a 2-dimensional weighted mean for this

Comment: You could create overlapping crops to make smooth borders by averaging over them or fading one into the other.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.